# Rebuilding the “next” branch after a feature release

Tags: git, release-management

The [manpage for Git Workflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) says:

> After a feature release, the integration branch next may optionally be rewound and rebuilt from the tip of master using the surviving topics on next:
>
> Recipe: Rewind and rebuild next
>
> ```
> git checkout next
> git reset --hard master
> git merge ai/topic_in_next1
> git merge ai/topic_in_next2
> ```

I understand the hard reset, but don’t understand the topic merges. Since this is after a release that had to go through *next* to *master*, wouldn’t *master* already contain the topics we are just merging to *next*? (Or are those topics the ones that didn’t make it to the release?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Git workflow, proposed experimental topic branches are on `pu`, features under review and potentially being part in the next release are in `next`. However not all topic branches in `next` automatically migrate to master. For Git in particularly Junio is picking weekly the topic branches that are merged from next to master and sent an overview of topics to the mailinglist. This is the "What's cooking in git.git" email.

The important part is that every merge from next to master is manual and hand-picked. All of next is not necessarily becoming master.

Therefore long running topic branches that are not 100% in good shape but are still under active development might stay on next during multiple release cycles. That's what "surviving" is referred too.